# Redirect on another page when I press a button

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I'm working on a project and I have a problem.
I have 2 pages.
First page is Default.aspx
Second page is Registration.aspx (with button Submit and Cancel)

What I want to do is to press a Button_Cancel on Registration.aspx to redirect me on page Default.aspx
I tried all possibilities like

```
Response.Redirect(Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Default.aspx"));
```

or `Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");`
but when I press button Cancel it do not redirect me on Default page.
Here is the code for buttons Submit and Cancel:

```
 //Submit Button
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        lblResult.Text = ("Words were successfully introduced. !");
        lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        Response.Write("Your registration is successful !");    
    }
    else
    {
        lblResult.Text = "Incorrect words. Please try again.";
        lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
  }

//Cancel Button
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

On Registration page I have some fields with UserName, Email, Password etc.
When I press Button_Cancel I receive Error Messages to complete that fields...

[url](http://postimg.org/image/dw2bhzxbh/)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
```

Note that this will redirect to `Default.aspx` in the root folder of your website.

Answer (score 0):

A long shot, but still... How about using a [PostBackUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute of a Button2 and create a [cross page postback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

In your .aspx page make property of "Button2_Click"  is **ValidationGroup="None"** and check !!